# Add myself to a GitHub organization

Tags: github

I just received login credentials for a GitHub organization. How can I add my personal GitHub account to the organization?

When I try to log into the organization, I get the following error message:

> That account is an organization, you can't log in to it. Try your personal account instead.

Comment: who is an admin or account owner for that org? Create your personal Github account and ask to be added as a member of that org

Answer (score 4):

I think an organization is not an account. An administrator or more are assigned to an organization and he/she/them manage it. You must to login using your administrator account credentials and then you can manage your organization.

You can find more information about GitHub Organizations [here](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations).